# Firebase onMessageReceived being called by clicking the notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

When the app is in the foreground or background by clicking the notification, the app calls the onMessageReceived event. I use click_action the notification. Is correct that?

I create a notification when the app is in the foreground and when I click on the notification it executes the method again and create another notification.

Answer (score 2):

onMessageReceived is a method that called when an android client receive a message from Firebase Cloud. Usually, we create a function to build notification in this method.

And for what happen when we click the notification, we can use a pendingIntent.

We can see the example from google in [this github repo](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java)

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


    // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
// [END receive_message]

/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 *
 * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
 */
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not onMessageReceived is called depends on a couple of things:

- A data message always results in onMessageReceived being called
- A notification message when the app is in the foreground results in onMessageReceived being called

When your app is in the background and you send a notification message an automatically generated notification is displayed.

See more about the two types of FCM messages [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages).

click_action can be used to specify which Activity is launched when the user taps on the automatically generated notification, if not specified the default Activity is launched. click_action is only available via the REST API at the moment.